Indirect effect present in separate models but disappears in full mediation analysis
I am wrote my thesis and looking forward to defending it. So my question is about indirect effects through a mediator.
I have the following situation:
$X$ (parental involvement in education) doesn't predict $Y$ (learning achievements). But $X$ predicts $M$ (students' motivation) and $M$ predicts $Y$. I used a mediation model to check if $M$ is a mediator between $X$ and $Y$. The results showed that with $M$, appeared significant way from $X$ to $Y$. How can I interpret this?

I am guessing when you say "doesn't predict" you mean that there is not s statistically significant relation. But look at the effect size both before and after mediation and interpret that.

The wording seems to indicate that you fit separate models and after you fit a different mediation model, so this is an assumption included in my answer.
If you find that there is a full mediation present when you fit the paths separately (the first case you describe) but you find the opposite with a mediation model (the second case you describe), it seems then that what was believed to be a mediation was potentially spurious, as the mediation model is not accounting for all of the regression paths rather than just each individually. This is because the variance in $M$ and $Y$ that can be attributed to $X$ is now being split into two regression paths, where the error $e$ in $M$ and $Y$ that can't be attributed to $X$ is also now separate (as shown with the separate error terms below from MacKinnon et al. 2007). Note that the independent variable here is $X$, the mediator here is $M$ and the dependent variable here is $Y$.

This is actually why the original Kenny & Barron (1986) 4-step approach to mediation is now considered long outdated (Kline, 2015), since one can technically have separate "meaningful" pathways that don't end up this way when estimated as a single path model. The typical way we fit mediation models is the full model rather than each path separately, and your outcome probably reflects why that matters.
Issues with Mediation and Significance
However, I'm going to assume based off the wording that when you say "does predict" or "doesn't predict" it is implied that what you mean is that these associations are either statistically significant or not. It is incredibly rare for a variable to have literally no association with another variable, so saying one variable can't predict another is wrong. But beyond that, using statistical significance as a barometer for the influence of variables in a mediation model shouldn't be the single determining factor. One needs to factor in the individual effects of each regression path in the full model, the magnitude of the indirect and total effects of $X$ on $Y$, and various other determinations (e.g. how much error is in each path?).
Unfortunately, this sort of determination based solely on statistical significance in mediation models is almost universally usually how it is framed. This is something that contributes to what Kline calls "the mediation myth", where common interpretations about mediation are wrong because of how they are fit (e.g. ignoring causal time ordering of effects, measurement error issues) or how they are interpreted (e.g. by only looking at statistical significance, see Kline, 2015, 2023).
As an example of why statistical significance can severely limit our understanding of the actual influence these variables have, suppose we have the following simulated data and it's model:
#### Load Library and Set Seed ####
library(lavaan)
library(broom)
set.seed(123)

#### Simulate Data ####
n <- 1000
X <- rnorm(n)
M <- 0.05*X + rnorm(n)
Y <- 0.05*M + 0.05*X + rnorm(n)
df <- data.frame(X = X, Y = Y, M = M)
pairs(df)

#### Fit LM Models Separately ####
fit.ols.1 <- lm(Y ~ X)
fit.ols.2 <- lm(M ~ X)
fit.ols.3 <- lm(Y ~ M)

##### Summarize Them ####
tidy(fit.ols.1)
tidy(fit.ols.2)
tidy(fit.ols.3)

#### Fit Model ####
model <- ' # direct effect
             Y ~ c*X
           # mediator
             M ~ a*X
             Y ~ b*M
           # indirect effect (a*b)
             ab := a*b
           # total effect
             total := c + (a*b)
         '

fit <- sem(model, data = df)

#### Summarize Full Model ####
summary(fit)

In our model summary, the effects of all our paths are statistically significant, but notice their slopes have a very low magnitude due to the way we simulated our data (there are $n=1000$ observations, which makes it so any minor effect can be determined significant):
Regressions:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  Y ~                                                 
    X          (c)    0.136    0.033    4.154    0.000
  M ~                                                 
    X          (a)    0.068    0.031    2.208    0.027
  Y ~                                                 
    M          (b)    0.087    0.034    2.570    0.010

If we estimate our direct and indirect effects, they are also quite poor, the indirect effect of $X$ on $Y$ merely $.006$ while the total effect is a pitiful value of $.142$:
Defined Parameters:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
    ab                0.006    0.004    1.675    0.094
    total             0.142    0.033    4.329    0.000

References

Baron, R. M., & Kenny, D. A. (1986). The moderator–mediator variable distinction in social psychological research: Conceptual, strategic, and statistical considerations. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 51(6), 1173–1182. https://doi.org/10.1037/0022-3514.51.6.1173
Kline, R. B. (2015). The mediation myth. Basic and Applied Social Psychology, 37(4), 202–213. https://doi.org/10.1080/01973533.2015.1049349
Kline, R. B. (2023). Principles and practice of structural equation modeling (5th ed.). The Guilford Press.
MacKinnon, D. P., Fairchild, A. J., & Fritz, M. S. (2007). Mediation analysis. Annual Review of Psychology, 58(1), 593–614. https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.psych.58.110405.085542

